# Kendo ASPNET MVC Grid Filter row, placing search icon or placeholder inside search

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

I am looking to add search icon or a placeholder string inside Kendo UI ASP .Net filter row, MVC code as in attached screenshot.[image]

Please find below code ASP .Net MVC:

```
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EaseOfApprovalModels.Models.HandShake>()
                    .Name("grid1")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyID).Visible(false);
                        .Filterable(x => x.Enabled(false)).Width(25).Title("");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyName).Width(200).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)).Title("Company Name");
                        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' onclick='SelectCompanyRow(this);' />").Width(50).Title("Status");

                    })
                    .Sortable()
                    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .ButtonCount(5))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(5)
                )
```

I don't find any option to add search icon or place html5 placeholder to provide, users to have a sense about available search boxes on grid columns for filter row.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to add the placeholder text on document ready.

something like this:

```
$(document).read(function(){
   $('input[data-text-field="{Your Column Title here}"')
      .prop('placeholder', "<insert some text>");
});
```

Just swap out the **data-text-field** element to the title you are giving this column/bound column name. If your not sure what it is then use the dev tools to expose that info for you.  Then just add change the place holder text to be what ever you want.

The other alternative is to provide the filter row template yourself and "craft" the control manually something like:

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.Title).Width(300).Filterable(filter =>
            filter.Cell(cell => cell.Template("someFilterHere"))
```

then using a function like this:

```
function someFilterHere(element)
    {
        var dataSource = $('#grid1').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

       element.element.removeAttr("data-bind");
        element.element.prop('placeholder', 'some search text here');
        element.element.kendoAutoComplete({
             dataSource: dataSource ,
            autoBind: true,
            serverFiltering: false,
            filter:"contains",
            dataTextField:"Title"
        }).data('kendoAutoComplete');
    }
```

This will then bind the new autocomplete control to the grid's datasource and present back the options available.

Personally I would create a new datasource for this control as using this method i.e. grabbing the grid's datasource may have some unfortunate consequences. such as unexpected grid refreshing

Note: this is shown as an example of what can be done.

For speed and less configuration the first option may be the most appropriate.

I have provided a dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/OrAVO with a demo of both methods in use.

Comment: Thanks David.

I know, we could achieve using JS/jQuery, what I am looking at some sort of configuration in razor syntax, which could be easily turn on/off, if required as we have been using quit a few kendo grids, in our application.

And seems like, there is also no way to add, an icon within the input text for search.

May be, we just left with the template option in cell.

Comment: Other than you creating a "custom" or overloaded version of the widget there isn't a config option that I know off within the mvc wrappers.